# Busy spinner while retrieving data

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to add a busy spinner while retrieving data from a Mysql database.
The code is written in PHP.
The problem is that it takes too long time to get back the result from Mysql database and I would like that the user get some indication that something is happening.

Is there a way to do that?

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
include "db.php"
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
    // This part takes too long time to execute

    $query = "SELECT * FROM bokings WHERE Bokningsnr = '83270'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $showid = $row['showid'];
        echo $showid."<br>";
    }

?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Regards.

/Oualid

Comment: Maybe you should try to improve the performance first.

Comment: There are many many ways to do this. Have you tried any particular approach yet?

Comment: Is the waiting time before the page actually renders? If so, there isn't much you can do in that respect. If you're using ajax, showing your code will get you fairly specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do that. It also depends on how you're calling the data.

the simple approach if youre using JQuery is to have an image with the spinning art. hide it initially and show it on an ajax call.

```
<img id="myspinner" src="yoursinnping.png" alt="processing please wait" style="display:none;"/>

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myajaxfunction();" />
```

then in an ajax call

```
function myajaxfunction () {
       $('#smyspinner).show();
        // do ajax call here
        //  on success  $('#smyspinner).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply take a .gif image with the spinning animation and place it on the screen (you will need to find an apropriate place for it) when you send a query to the db. the image can be found [here](http://mentalized.net/activity-indicators/indicators/ilcu/roller.gif)